# .strip() and .split() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task of program:

1. Delete all punctuation marks and split string2 to words
2. Then each word put in list2
3. Put each word of string1 in list1
4. Print lists

Code:

```
import string 

str1 = "abc, 'bca'"
str2 = "abc, 'bca'"

str2.strip(string.punctuation)
str2.split()

list1 = []
list2 = []
for s in str1:
    list1.append(s)
for s in str2:
    list2.append(s)

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(string.punctuation)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', ',', ' ', "'", 'b', 'c', 'a', "'"] #list1
['a', 'b', 'c', ',', ' ', "'", 'b', 'c', 'a', "'"] #list2

!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ #string.punctuation
```

list2 should not have any spaces or punctuation. Why is it returning the same values as the unstripped, unsplit list?

Comment: Try delete the `strip` and the `split` lines and see the output...

Answer (score 1):

You are making two mistakes:

- You are *ignoring* the return values of `str.strip()` and `str.split()`. Strings are immutable, these methods return *new* objects.
- You are stripping, then splitting, leaving punctuation *between* words in place, because stripping only removes characters from the start and end.

Split first, then strip, and store the results:

```
result = [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in str2.split()]
```

I used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to process each result from the `str2.split()` call in turn:

```
>>> import string
>>> str2 = "abc, 'bca'"
>>> [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in str2.split()]
['abc', 'bca']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all punctuation marks and split string2 to words
2. Then each word put in list2

then, you can:

```
>>> ''.join([i for i in str2 if i not in string.punctuation])
'abc bca'
```

---

> 3. Put each word of string1 in list1

I don't understand this one.

---

by the way, remember assign the result, or you'll loss them.

> str2.strip(string.punctuation)
>
> str2.split()

the reason why list1 == list2 is you just add each element in str1 and str2 to list1 and list2, str1 equals to str2, so list1 equals to list2